# Grammar of Java for Method Signatures

Tags: java, grammar

I'm working on a project that **requires the user to input a method signature**. My code takes that signature and does something with it.

But to be able to do something with it, I need to break the method signature into pieces and store those pieces in relevant variables like modifiers, methodReturnType, methodName, paramModifiers, paramType, paramName, exceptions.

To achieve this, I'm putting the logic in my code manually. Also, I'm using HashMap for modifiers and TreeSet for exceptions. Now, there can be a lot of ways a method signature looks. So my questions/ doubts are:

1. I think there should be some better way inside java already to achieve this. Because the compiler understands the grammar of Java... Or something inside the class java.lang.reflect.Method that I can't figure out...There must be some way. Does anybody know about that?
2. I welcome any suggestions towards improving my existing logic... Should I prefer other collections over this... or any other way... anything.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer you are looking for is this.

http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/reflect/generics/parser/SignatureParser.html

Comment: Please provide more than [just a link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/242899).

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I'm looking for. So I tried to work with it and I wrote this:

`MethodTypeSignature mts = SignatureParser.make().parseMethodSig(method);`


Upon running this, however, I'm getting these exceptions:
_java.lang.reflect.GenericSignatureFormatError
 at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.error(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseFormalParameters(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseMethodTypeSignature(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseMethodSig(Unknown Source)_

Comment: Here method was a string. `method = "public static void main(String[] args)";`

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using this code, it will loop through all methods of a classe and try to print them, print their modifiers :

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName(SomeClass.class);
Method[] allMethods = c.getDeclaredMethods();

for (Method m : allMethods) {
 out.format("%s%n", m.toGenericString());
 out.format("  Modifiers:  %s%n",Modifier.toString(m.getModifiers()));
}
```

Take a look here, there are some others examples http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/method.html